# Add a GridView to a ListView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, listview

I'm trying to create a ListView that will consist of two types of elements: Strings and a GridView.
I.e. putting both Strings and a GridView inside one single ListView.

The layout should look something like this:

- String Item 1.1
- String Item 1.2
- String Item 1.3
- String Item 1.4
- GridView Item 1 GridView Item 2 
  GridView Item 3 GridView Item 4
- String Item 2.1
- String Item 2.2
- String Item 2.3
- String Item 2.4

Is there any way to do this?

As per now I can only show the first item in the GridView, and it acts just as a regular String element in the ListView.

The code can be viewed here:

- [CustomListViewActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/DDbgwQs4)
- [SectionAdapter.java](http://pastebin.com/6muQUiCQ)
- [main.xml](http://pastebin.com/F92mki90)
- [header_row.xml](http://pastebin.com/9G7KmWv3)
- [simple_list_row.xml](http://pastebin.com/DmvgWVG5)
- [grid_list_row.xml](http://pastebin.com/6qdP5Zcr)

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4536955/367101) I created this class that works very well:

```
public class NonScrollableGridView extends GridView {
    public NonScrollableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Do not use the highest two bits of Integer.MAX_VALUE because they are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
        getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this task, if the grid it has a lot of data, all is painted at the same time, there are not recycle issues on this grid, and could get out of memory ... there must be a way ... maybe with recycle views?

Comment: This is a very old question/answer. It could easily be solved by e.g. RecyclerView now. Take a look here for instance: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html

Comment: @greve you made my day. That approach works perfectly

Comment: Thanks mate! My problems don't normally get solved this easily!

Comment: Perfect answer . Thanks.