# How to disable GridView scrolling in Android?

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using a GridView for a game board. Recently some users have had problems with the board scrolling vertically (on Samsung Galaxy / Vibrant phones running 2.2) -- This bug does not occur on my Nexus One.

One user produced some [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r2k3.jpg) of the problem.

How could I lock the GridView in place? Is there a way to disable scrolling?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try to add or override `setOnTouchListener` for `GridView`,
then in `onTouch` method you can use code like this to 
make `gridView` not scrollable

**Java**

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
    }

});
```

**Kotlin**

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
}
```

Comment: This is a correct solution and should be accepted answer to the question.

Comment: Its also stopping onItemClick triggering of GridView. How to prevent this?

Comment: What would be the code to re-enable the GridView's scrolling, if you needed to?

Answer (score 11):

You can try setEnabled(false), although it might have other side effects. GridView is really not meant to be used the way you are using it. You should create your own custom view or layout. You could also use a TableLayout.

Comment: Yep, I realize it should be a custom view. Will be a bit more involved to replace the current GridView (Early design error). Was hoping there would be a quick fix :) The setEnabled() method disables all functionality. Thanks Romain

Comment: Romain Guy reeeeally does not want you to use a GridView without scrolling. I use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4536955/671543 trick.

Comment: For future readers I have found one example with TableLayout:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8639461/3844201