# How can I disable scroll of a grid view

Tags: android, gridview

I have a background image in a gridview  and I want to disable the scroll of the gridview, so that it doesnt scroll the image. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have u tried `setEnabled(false)`

Comment: yes i have tried but it doesnt have any effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852867/how-to-disable-gridview-scrolling-android/) if you want avoid GridView scrolling.

Comment: gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 
});

Answer (score 6):

use `gridview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false)` to disable vertical scroll bar.

Comment: always amazed to see that a 2-line question is already too long to read for some.

Comment: it dint work in my case :( cud i be missin something ?

Comment: What this does, is just removes the scroll bar. Nothing else changes.