# Custom TableLayout with multiple TextViews in rows

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to crate custom TableLayout with rows like this:

TV is for TextView, i.e. I want to add 11 TextViews to the row:

[image]

Each row begins with a title and then I add 5 pairs of  TextViews, so that table row is as wide, as screen is. 
**Here's my code:**

```
public class FlowTable extends TableLayout {

    private Context context;

    public FlowTable(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public FlowTable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addContent(List<ResultItem> data) {

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                this.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tableRow = new TableRow(context);
                TextView tvRange = new TextView(context);
                tvRange.setLayoutParams(params);
                tvRange.setText(genRange(i+1));
                tableRow.addView(tvRange);

            }
            TextView tvDistance = new TextView(context);
            tvDistance.setLayoutParams(params);
            tvDistance.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(i).distance));

            TextView tvResult = new TextView(context);
            tvResult.setLayoutParams(params);
            tvResult.setText(data.get(i).result);

            tableRow.addView(tvDistance);
            tableRow.addView(tvResult);
        }
    }

    private String genRange(int currIndex){
        /********************/
        return somestring;
    }
}
```

**Using table:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <packagename.FlowTable
        android:id="@+id/flowTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In fragment:**

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_summary, container, false);
        FlowTable flowTable = (FlowTable)root.findViewById(R.id.flowTable);
        flowTable.addContent(data);
```

**The problem:** the screen is just empty! Nothing at all. Before I added the layout params to textview it worked, but row didn't occupy the screen width. My initial solution was based on the LinearLayout samples, because TableRow is an extention of LinearLayout. But I can't make it work.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but try to add `android:stretchColumns="*"` to your `<FlowTable>` tag. Else, I would also try to use another `addView` overload : `tableRow.addView(tvRange, params)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try programmatically setting all columns to stretch (didn't seem to work in XML for me):

```
...
flowTable.addContent(data);
flowTable.setStretchAllColumns(true);
```

Some other quick facts:

- No need to try and specify height and width **for TableRow within TableLayout** because it will always be height=WRAP_CONTENT and width=MATCH_PARENT. See [TableLayout documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) where this is listed in the Class Overview section
- No need to try and specify height and widget **for children of TableRow** because they will always be height=WRAP_CONTENT and width=MATCH_PARENT. See [TableRow documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) where this is listed in the Class Overview section

Might I also humbly suggest a bit of refactoring:

```
public class FlowTable extends TableLayout {
    private TableRow mCurrentRow;

    public FlowTable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FlowTable(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mCurrentRow = new TableRow(getContext());
        mCurrentRow.addView(createAndFillTextView("0")); // title for first row
        setStretchAllColumns(true);
    }

    public void addContent(List<ResultInfo> data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if ((i % 5 == 0) && (i != 0) /** Don't do this on 0! */) {
                finishRowAndStartNew(i);
            }

            mCurrentRow.addView(createAndFillTextView(data.get(i).distance));
            mCurrentRow.addView(createAndFillTextView(data.get(i).result));
        }
    }

    private void finishRowAndStartNew(int newRowIndex) {
        addView(mCurrentRow);
        mCurrentRow = new TableRow(getContext());
        mCurrentRow.addView(createAndFillTextView(genRange(newRowIndex+1)));
    }

    private String genRange(int currIndex){
        /********************/
        return String.valueOf(currIndex);
    }

    private TextView createAndFillTextView(String text) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setText(text);        
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've removed params and added flowTable.setStretchAllColumns(true); It works now!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the xml Layout for that then try this:

```
    <TableLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableRow android:weightSum="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:text="Title" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- First Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- Second Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <!-- Third Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!-- Fourth Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- Fifth Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:weightSum="1">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:text="Title" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- First Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- Second Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <!-- Third Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!-- Fourth Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- Fifth Group -->
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv1"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/totalText" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:text="Tv2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Hope it will help you. . . 
And if you want other then xml then let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to convert that to programmatic layout creation.

Comment: Yes Sure. And if you not get the desire output then let me know.