# Android define a custom group view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view, custom-view

I'm implementing a dialler screen and I want to make the keypad as a custom view (so that I can embed it directly in other UI if needed)

I've defined a layout xml file keypad.xml so I'm able to show the keypad at least in my dialler screen. I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically make it as a KeypadView class (using keypad.xml layout) so that when I need the same layout again, I could embed it by calling

```
<com.example.KeypadView ..></com.example.KeypadView>
```

[Claim!!!] I did read the android tutorial on [creating custom views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). It uses custom drawings.. I don't want it to be so complicated... I already have a template defined in keypad.xml I want to use that layout in my KeypadView.java and also, I want to detect the onTapKey event inside the KeypadView class and use a listener interface to pass the event to whoever want to handle it..

Something like [this exmaple](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Comment: Helpful for u http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/User-Event/Exampleofwritinganinputmethodforasoftkeyboard.htm

Comment: Did you even try to read the Android documentation? https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: @RichieHH thanks for reminding me.. I read! but still have no much idea on the implementation for my need....

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using only xml in android. First you create your custom layout say keypad.xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:layout_height=”match_parent”
```

> ........

Now you can use above custom view anywhere you want by using keyword include.
For example in your dialer.xml you can do:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:layout_height=”match_parent”>

<include layout="@layout/keypad"/>

<TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/your_no"
          android:padding="10dp" />

...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I upvote it, but it's not really what I'm looking for. My fault, but I don't know how to describe it clearly

Comment: I think you should post some of your code too, so that you can be more specific in what's your actual problem is.

Comment: you're right. I found hints from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554181/custom-tablelayout-with-multiple-textviews-in-rows will update my solution later