# Disable GridView from scrolling under some conditions

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have a `GridView` where I load a preview image over the `GridView`. While my preview is shown I want to disable scrolling. My code looks like that:

```
grid.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            preview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Log.d("test", "isShown: " + preview.isShown());
            return preview.isShown();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Pretty simple, but this does not work perfect. Scrolling is disabled by consuming the events, but it seems that the first move event gets every time executed on the `GridView` and it moves for some pixels just one time.

What confuses me is that I get not `isShown: false` messages in the logcat after seting `preview` to visble. So far this is also no obvious reacing condition. This means that all events which get cought by my listener returns `true` as expected.

I read this almost dublicates and many more:

- [How to disable GridView scrolling in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4852867/995926)
- [How to disable scrolling in GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8908228/995926)

But there is the point about how to disable it. I figgered that out my self.