# How to get the display of 9x9 grid in the android?

Tags: android, user-interface, grid, cell

Now it's time to explore Android for me. I have designed one ui which is shown below, The thing is I am getting confused with what should I do in the first frame in order to get 9x9 grid. Actually the same thing I developed in core java by placing 81 JTextFields in each cell using for loops and with the help of gridbaglayout and I got my application perfectly working. But in android how can I define my 9x9 cells in xml, so that it should accept numbers and entered numbers should be retrieved too in order to validate the sudoku rules. Following is my code and diagram. Can anyone suggest how to make the frame 1 to have 9x9 cells? If I use   TextEdit in my xml file, it would be 81 textfields, and if I use Canvas(I am thinking, don't know whether it is possible), it seems to me impossible to make it accept numbers and to retrieve from that canvas board. I really appreciate if anyone could help. Please go easy, if it seems silly question(which I hope not,  as I tried 2 days for it), as I am new to android. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#0f0"
        />
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fLayout2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#00f">

        <TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/keypad"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="*">

<TableRow >
    <Button android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:text="validate"
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    </Button>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the UI

[image].

Comment: Either [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) or [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) both are useful for you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Grid View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

> **GridView** is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the layout using a ListAdapter.

Comment: Even I thought to apply GridView, but my doubt is how to arrange things, so that it should accept numbers and that numbers should be retrieved. I am thinking to arrange EditTexts, but in xml it's very lengthy to arrange 81 EditTexts.

Comment: Use Adapter and create dynamically EditText at runtime.. You don't need to maintain xml file for 81 EditText..

Comment: Even I got one more problem, I don't want my frame1 to be scrollable. The entire 9x9 cells should automatically get fit to the frame1.

Comment: Hey, I created 81 edittexts by using two for loops with two dimensional array edittexts. which adapter I have to use in order to attach 2 dimensional edittexts to gridview? Because i am getting errors if add them with ListAdapter.

Comment: Please don't mind, I might be troubling you. But hope you help with this last question.

Comment: Look at the links http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html and http://collegewires.com/android/2012/06/android-grid-view-example/ find example from it. And modified according your requirements.

Comment: There is no such method as setScrollable(false); that can be applied to gridview.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852867/how-to-disable-gridview-scrolling-android/

Comment: I tried all those before asking you, but they don't have effect on my application. Still there is scrolling.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this Open Sudoku Project from [Git Hub](https://github.com/romario333/opensudoku/tree/master/OpenSudoku) . Here you can find layout and source code for Sudoku.

Check  **res/layout/sudoku_edit.xml** for Sudoku View.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="9" 

>
</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```