# ScrollView is not applied to whole layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-scrollview, android-gridlayout

I want to add a `LinearLayout` to `ScrollView` where the children of `LinearLayout` are a bunch of `GridLayouts` containing 4 columns. The items in the `GridLayout` is dynamically populated from the code. The `GridLayout` can have either 2 or 1 rows depending upon the number of content set in MainRows class.

Now, since there can be many sets of `GridLayout`, so a `ScrollView` is required. The problem is, `ScrollView` only scrolls 2 rows of Grids. This 2 rows is in one set of MainRows, if that makes sense. I want to scroll all the Grids contained in the layout.

Here is my **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/topEight"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**single_video_grid.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:numColumns="4">
</GridView>
```

And from the code I am dynamically adding and setting views like this:

```
            ArrayList<MainRows> rows = JSONVideoDataHandler.getRowElements();
            for (MainRows row : rows) {
                LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
                if(row instanceof Ads){
                    // TODO implement ads layout
                }else{
                    int numberOfItems = row.getNumberOfItems();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    if(numberOfItems > 4){
                        GridView gridview = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_video_grid, null);
                        // if number of vids exceeds 4, 2 rows are required.
                        // therefore setting 8 imageplaceholders.
                        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, row, 8));
                        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "haha " + position,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        parentLayout.addView(gridview);
                    }else{
                        GridView gridview = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_video_grid, null);
                        // if number of vids does not exceed 4, 1 row is required.
                        // therefore setting 4 imageplaceholders.
                        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, row, 4));
                        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "haha " + position,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
//                      linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
                        parentLayout.addView(gridview);
                    }
                }
```

Let me know if the question is not clear enough. I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you exclusively have to use Grid Layouts. Why not do like this, just make sure framelayout's width is screenWidth / 4.

```
<scrollview>
 <linearlayout> // vertical
  for i < categories {
   <linerlayout> // horizontal
    for j < videos {
     <framelayout>
      // the content you want to show
     </framelayout>
    }
   </linearlayout>
  }
 </linearlayout>
</scrollview>
```

Comment: This is a nice and simple idea. But I would really want to see why my GridLayout is not working. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @siz has explained why. If you badly want to use GridLayouts then force them to stop scrolling. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852867/how-to-disable-gridview-scrolling-android/) on your grid views.

Comment: Hmmm true. Guess I have to change my layout. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, youare running into issues because a GridView inherently has a scroll view within itself. So putting a GridView inside a ScrollView really nullifies the purpose of the SrollView as the GridView's scrolling behavior trumps. Take a look at this question and answer as it addresses this very problem. [How to put GridView inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859250/how-to-put-gridview-inside-scrollview)

Comment: Hmm i guess that's why the 2 rows of `GridView` is scrolling, not the whole layout. To be more clear, I want some kind of structure like this:
<GridView ....
.... </GridView> <linebreak>
<GridView ....
.... </GridView>

If we have many gridviews like i showed above, I want it all to scroll rather than scroll the rows of gridview itself.