# Adapt a GridView cell's height to remaining space

Tags: android, android-gridview

Well, my question is quite simple.

I am beginning Android programming and I am programming a simple calendar app.

My main layout is like this (There's more above the RelativeLayout, but I think it's not important):

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:id
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/month_days"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:columnWidth="60dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the GridView to use every single pixel in the Layout, in height and in width. I could adjust de columnWidth property to gain that, but I don't know how to do this with height.

I was thinking in getting the RelativeLayout dimensions (height particularly), and dividing it by 6, which is the number of rows I want... But I'm not sure if this is correct neither how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Something I did not say: I have a custom adapter to populate the GridView and its properties. Here's the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/actual_month_day" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/day_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I change `android:layout_height="65dp"`, for example, it makes the cell bigger, which is something similar to what I want, but it does not cover the entire screen. If I write a bigger value I need to scroll to see the whole grid.

The problem is the value. I want the "65dp" to be dynamic and change depending on the free space in the screen.

If it helps, here's the `getView()` in my adapter.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v;
    TextView actualDay;

    if (convertView == null) {
        v = new View(c);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_2, parent, false);
        actualDay = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.day_2);
        actualDay.setText(days[position]);

        if(!isActualMonth(position)) v.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.not_actual_month_day));
    } else {
        v = (View) convertView;
    }

    return v;       
}
```

I think that I have to calculate the Layout's remaining space in the `getView()` code, but I don't know how.

I've tried adding `actualDay.setHeight(parent.getHeight()/6);` but it didn't help me too much. The cell's height is ok, but it scrolls up and then everything disappears. After that, I set `android:scrollbars="none"`, but still nothing.

I do not know what's the problem here. Maybe the logic is fine, but the property of the scrollbar is not what I need. Sorry if it is all a bit messy, but I wanted to tell you the things I've tried.

Thank you again.

Comment: I want to confirm one thing: you want to have the grid fill the screen, so do you need any scrolling?  As in will you ever have a case where you will have more items than the screen size can fill?

Comment: No. It's the calendar main grid... Always 6x7. So, I don't need any scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use your code (if the height looks well)

actualDay.setHeight(parent.getHeight()/6);

and disable the scrolling for the gridview. The following link has code that shows how to disable scrolling [How to disable GridView scrolling in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852867/how-to-disable-gridview-scrolling-in-android).

Comment: It worked! But I think I might have to change something else. One of my ideas is to scroll left/right to change month. If I keep using this function I think I cannot do that, can I? Anyway, this works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But it didn't work. =( I've just added more info to the post. Maybe it wasn't very clear.