# make a girdview non-scrollable when sliding drawer is opened

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-scroll, non-scrolling

I have a `SlidingDrawer` as a sibling of `GridView`, when the sliding drawer is opened and if its scrolled (inside sliding drawer) the grid view which is behind is also scrolled.

I implemented like :

```
@Override
    public void onDrawerOpened() {
    gridView.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
    public void onDrawerClosed() {
    gridView.setEnabled(true);
}
```

and also implemented with `OnTouchListener()` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496632/1778834) thread, but its still get scrolled.

**NOTE** : Above impl. works in the case where each item in the gridview is non-click-able, but if each item in gridview is click-able, its get scrolled

**UPDATE :**
Actually, `setEnabled()` and `OnTouchListener()` is not working because while scrolling the focus goes to the inner elements (where click listener is set) of the gridview and it make the gridview scrolled. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: found a work around :) - in sliding drawer you can find `android:content` defined in the context layout give `android:clickable="true"` so now the focus is on the content and not on the grid view or its items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around,

**sliding_drawer.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Slider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" >                 <---- Make the content click able so the focus goes to this and makes the list, grid view at back to stop scrolling.

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TetxtView 1" />
</LinearLayout>
```