# Cannot remove scrollbar from gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have read and tried all of the stackoverflow questions about removing/hiding a scrollbar from a gridview, however, it wont disappear! I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Lollipop.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llChooserContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvGallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/chooser_grid_col_width"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my `onCreate`

```
    llChooserContainer.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    llChooserContainer.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    gvGallery.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    gvGallery.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    gvGallery.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    gvGallery.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
```

Also tried setting styles like

```
    gvGallery.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

and setting size to null:

```
    gvGallery.setScrollBarSize(0);
```

and thumb to null

```
android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"
```

There is nothing in the XML -> styles.xml I also tried cleaning the project, invalidating caches, uninstalling the app every time.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852867/how-to-disable-gridview-scrolling-in-android

Comment: removing `fastScrollEnabled` finally resolved my issue! Thank you! You could add that as the answer

Comment: i add my answer below please accept it.if it work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, remove the below property from gridview:

```
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
```

Answer (score 7):

you can try this

```
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

or

```
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
```