# Is there any way to scroll the scrollbar of gridview/listview inside Scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi in my application the screen is so large which contains a gridview with images and listview with lot of list items and also so many text views existed in my screen. so that i placed this content in scrollview to view on the mobile screen. When I placed the content in the scrollview then the gridview/listview scroll is not working.

Is there any way to solve this issue. I referred so many links but i could not get the solution.

The links are
[Grid of images inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523609/grid-of-images-inside-scrollview)
[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

etc

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it using following code, but I suggest please change UI, it is not according android guideline. it' easily scrolled in iPhone interface.

```
final ScrollView childScroll = (ScrollView)
view.findViewById(R.id.resourceactivity_sv_classes_detail);

parentScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//Log.v(TAG,"PARENT TOUCH");
childScroll.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent
(false); return false; } }); childScroll.setOnTouchListener(new
View.OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//Log.v(TAG,"CHILD TOUCH");
v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); return
false; } });
```

You can modify gridview instead of child scrollview.