# How to put GridView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I have to design layout such that whole layout should scroll and inside layout I have to display related content in `Grid` form so I decided to use `GridView`.But problem is that I’m unable to use `GridView` inside `ScrollView` I have read documentation(Documentation also saying that we should not use `GridView` inside `ScrollView`) also.But I have to do this,so can any please give me some idea about this.Thanks

Comment: don't. you can't. (ok, you can, but it is painful (doesn't quite fit), so try to avoid it).

Comment: Thanks @njzk2 But i have to desing layout like this so can u please tell me some other way that should look like this.

Comment: @Dipu: You mention just the `GridView` in a `ScrollView`. In the comment to the first answer, you mention adding more `Views` to the, I assume, `ScrollView`. Considering rephrasing your question to include as many details as possible.

Comment: Actually, you can, and there are some good applications for it. I will update with an answer.

Comment: @SiddharthLele i mean i have to put ImageView,TextView,Button and GridView inside listview.At button have to put GridView that's why it's necessary to use scrollview

Comment: have you tried encapsulating gridview with a linear layout ?

Comment: here is exact ans for toy i think..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523609/grid-of-images-inside-scrollview/4536955#4536955

Comment: Do not do this, that will cause all items even if those items which are not visible in current screen call getview() when gridview initialize，that certainly cost a lot of time.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

There are definitely benefits to a GridView beside the inherent scrolling. For example, a consistent, dynamic layout of cells that will expand and contract based on the data you pass into it. So, when people say it's not good to desire such a functionality, I think that's wrong because you could want the dynamic grid of images (views) inside of a scrolling view, but want that entire scrolling view to contain other things than just the grid cells.

Now, here is how you can do this. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut). It is an expandable height GridView, which you will want to import / create in your project. What that basically  means is that as more items are added to the GridView, it will just expand its height, as opposed to keeping its height set and using scrolling. This is exactly what you want.

Once you have the ExpandableHeightGridView in your project, go to your XML layout where you want the GridView to be. You can then do something like this (paraphrasing):

```
<ScrollView ...>
    <RelativeLayout ...>
        <com.example.ExpandableHeightGridView ... />
        <other view items />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then, in your activity where you set the GridView's adapter, you want to make sure you set it to expand. So:

```
ExpandableHeightGridView gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.myId);
gridView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
gridView.setExpanded(true);
```

The reason you want this expandable GridView is because, the fact that a standard GridView doesn't expand is what causes it to scroll. It sticks to a certain height, and then as more items fill it past its view bounds, it becomes scrollable. Now, with this, your GridView will always expand its height to fit the content within it, thus never allowing it to enter its scrolling mode. This enables you to use it inside of the ScrollView and use other view elements above or below it within the ScrollView, and have them all scroll.

This should give you the result you're looking for. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: one thing,when i launch app with different view then layout automatically scroll at bottom how to fit it please suggest me

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "launch app with different view." I haven't run into this issue.

Comment: This GridView is taking focus and placing at top position of the screen doing scroll while changing the view's visibility like visible->gone->visible. With this, scroll is applying by default. Actually, It shouldn't happen. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Jaan please how did you fixed the issue: "when i launch app with different view then layout automatically scroll at bottom"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998819/display-positioned-at-the-bottom-of-the-list

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you lose the performance optimizations that the grid view gives you, ie. recycling of grid items.

Comment: That's a good point. However, I'm not quite sure there would be any other approach to solve that, outside of extending GridView and/or creating a custom view to handle recycling.

Comment: What you suggest in this answer defeats the point of a `GridView`. Your app could run out of memory and the performance would suffer greatly. The solution is using header or footer views just like with a normal `ListView`. The native `GridView` may not support header or footer views, but there are [**custom implementations like this one**](https://github.com/maurycyw/HeaderGridView) that do. Use one of those and you get the same effect without loosing view recycling. Hacks like you propose may solve the problem, but they will just cause more serious problems later on.

Comment: Or you could just use a `GridLayout` in the `ScrollView`. There would again be no view recycling, but it would at least be a lot better than using a `GridView`. [**Link to documentation.**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

Comment: @XaverKapeller  will your GridLayout in a scrollview will work for more than one gridviews i want in actual sections gridview  but every section should contain header and footer so i did not get any lib thats why i m using two gridviews do u have any sol in your mind ?

Comment: put gridView.setFocusable(false); before setting expanded true to prevent scrollview scrolls automatically till the GridView end.

Comment: Wanted to tell about a behaviour that happened when implementing this is that the expanded gridview took the scrollview to the bottom, so just wanted to point that doing this : 

        //moving back the ScrollLayout to the top, as expanding the gridview will move the scrollview to the bottom
        ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById (R.id.scrollView);
        mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);

will put everything in place. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Genius! Thank you!

Comment: Like @XaverKapeller said this solution is not suitable in terms of performance, especially with a large number of elements, which is the main objective of using GridView or listview . There are several ways to solve this problem more performance while respecting the main goal of gridview!

Answer (score 36):

I know I'm late but I have another solution which I must share and which works flawlessly. Here, the method calculates the GridView height based on the number of items it contains and sets the height to the GridView at run time.

```
public void setGridViewHeightBasedOnChildren(GridView gridView, int columns) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = gridView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int items = listAdapter.getCount();
        int rows = 0;

        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(0, null, gridView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        float x = 1;
        if( items > columns ){
            x = items/columns;
            rows = (int) (x + 1);
            totalHeight *= rows;
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight;
        gridView.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

After you have called `setAdapter` on your gridview, just call

```
setGridViewHeightBasedOnChildren( <yourGridView> , <no of grid view columns> )
```

and it'll work.

You can the define the gridview in your xml as you normally do

and let the code take care of it. :)

Comment: did you call setAdapter on your gridview before calling the setGridViewHeightBasedOnChildren method? If the gridview has items then it should work.

Comment: @vickey if the number of items completely fills the number of rows, the height you calculated has 1 extra row

Comment: If your GridView has vertical spacing, you have to add it to totalHeight.

Comment: There is a bug in this code. replace if block with:  

 if( items > columns ){
            x = ((double) items ) /columns;
            rows =(int) Math.ceil(x);
            totalHeight *= rows;
        }

and declare x veriable as double istead of float.

Comment: If you don't want to use custom grid view with this code its working

Comment: How do I get the columns number if gridview is set to android:numColumns="auto_fit" ?

Answer (score 10):

I found a way to give the **GridView** a fixed size **inside ScrollView**, and **enable scrolling** it. That allows you to see the entire ScrollView without having to scroll all elements of the GridView, and it makes more sense to me that using an *ExpandableHeightGridView*.

To do so, you would have to implement a new class extending GridView and override *onTouchEvent()* to call *requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)*.
Thus, the parent view will leave the Grid intercept touch events.

*GridViewScrollable.java:*

```
package com.example;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GridViewScrollable extends GridView {

    public GridViewAdjuntos(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GridViewAdjuntos(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GridViewAdjuntos(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        // Called when a child does not want this parent and its ancestors to intercept touch events.
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Add it in your layout with the characteristics and margins you want, inside a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="true" >

    <com.example.GridViewScrollable
    android:id="@+id/myGVS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</ScrollView>
```

And just get it in your activity:

```
GridViewScrollable myGridView = (GridViewScrollable) findViewById(R.id.myGVS);
```

I hope it helps =)

In Kotlin:

```
class GridViewScrollable @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : GridView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        // Called when a child does not want this parent and its ancestors to intercept touch events.
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev)
    }
}
```

There is an annoying warning: "Custom view GridViewScrollable overrides onTouchEvent but not performClick". Please, resolve yourself if you want.

Comment: It's pretty late but this gridview can scroll?

Comment: It does work for me but the problem is that fling does not work.

Comment: @ievgen Did you put android:isScrollContainer="true" in your ScrollView?

Comment: This is the only way I could get the GridView to work with a list of variable sized radio buttons. I really did not want to have a scroll bar but the GridView seems to get confused and truncate the last row if it is too large.

Comment: What is ```GridViewAdjuntos```?

Comment: @Ivan, hah, the author forgot to rename it to `GridViewScrollable` in code. :)

Comment: Thanks! Inside `RecyclerView` it shows one row of `GridView`, as usual, but enables scrolling inside `GridView`.

Answer (score 10):

I was also trying to make a `GridView` scrollable inside a `NestedScrollView`.

This answer on another question helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38612612

> Enable your GridView Property as
>
> ```
> android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
> ```

Original poster: [Droid_Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685804/droid-dev)

Comment: very useful tanxxx

Answer (score 5):

To use gridview inside scrollview, set scrollview android:fillViewport="true"

I know its late to answer here but may be useful to some new developers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have used dennisdrew's answer and you have content above your grid and it gets hidden when you open your view simply add the last line below

```
ExpandableHeightGridView gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.myId);
gridView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
gridView.setExpanded(true);
gridView.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `ExpandableHeightlistView` or `ExpandableHeightGridView` inside `scrollview`.

**Logic**

Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint. But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.

```
int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
 Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
 super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
 params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
```

for further information explore the example below with demo

http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/make-android-listview-gridview-expandable-inside-scrollview/

Comment: Can you please describe some background information as to why one is better compared to the other?

Answer (score 1):

i would not force the issue.  GridView does not work well in a scrollView. instead convert your gridview into a recyclerview and use a gridLayoutManager to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Trust this solution worked for me!

android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

The code above inside grid view enables to scroll gridview
and set width and height
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200sp"

This will work even inside scrollview
Thanks for the previous answers I figured out this for the previous answers.
Thanks to them

Answer (score 0):

```
 gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

// Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside ScrollView

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `GridView` inside `ScrollView` / `RecyclerView`, there are 2 cases:

1. If you want to have `GridView` with all rows visible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63724794/2914140.
2. If you want to have one row visible in `GridView`, but be able to scroll it (to reveal other rows), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26852498/2914140.