# Display positioned at the bottom of the list

Tags: android, gridview

On Nexus S and WildFire when displaying my `ExpandableHeightGridView`, the `activity` view is positioned at the bottom of the `scrollview` by default.
when i launch app, `ExpandableHeightGridView` with different view then main `layout` automatically scroll at bottom!!!
Did any one faced the same problem?

Here is my `ExpandableHeightGridView`:

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {

    // Attributes
    private boolean mExpanded = true;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (isExpanded()) {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        mExpanded = expanded;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return mExpanded;
    }
}
```

My main xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/program_showview_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/program_showview_padding_top">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/program_category"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/program_vignette"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/program_sub_category"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/program_category"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/program_vignette"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/program_duration"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/program_sub_category"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/program_vignette"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/program_csa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/program_duration"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/program_vignette"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/program_tweets_count"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/program_csa"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/program_vignette"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/program_summary_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/program_vignette"
            android:text="@string/program_showview_summary" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/program_summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/program_summary_label" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/program_casting_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/program_summary"
            android:text="fffffff" />
        <fr.haploid.widget.ExpandableHeightGridView
            android:id="@+id/program_casting"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/program_casting_label"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting your scrollview to not be focusable. I had the same problem and this fixed it.

```
yourExpandableHeightGridView.setFocusable(false);
```

or

```
android:focusable="false"
```

in XML.