# gridview second row doesn't appear when set height to warp content

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm adding a ImageView item to the empty GridView programmatically so when i set the height 
to wrap content the second row disappears.

Here's the gridview xml :

```
    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="100dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dip" />
```

I tried to set the hight to wrap content programmatically after adding the items but it didn't work, and i know that i can't predifine the number of rows, and i don't want to set a fixed height.

Any help ?

Comment: what is the parent viewgroup of you GridView?

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have your GridView inside the ScrollView;

Problem GridView doesn't expand inside the Scroll view.

Please refer the following post.

[Please Follow the Stackoverflow post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12859616/3048383)

Answer (score 0):

Make your ParentLayout to **fill_parent** and then make GridView **wrap_content**.

Comment: Then you have to create another sub parent layout for this, take your GridView into new Sub Parent layout and make it match_parent or fill_parent.