# How to use ChrisBanes' ActionBar-PullToRefresh library with Fragments having GridViews

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to use Chris Banes' library [Actionbar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh). It can be found [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh).

I am using Tabs + ViewPager + Fragments in my app.

**The problem I'm facing is that my fragment has a `GridView` and I cannot figure out how to use this library to work with it.**

I read through the sample code. He says that all you have to do is, wrap your refreshable view in a `PullToRefreshLayout` like this:

```
<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Your content, here we're using a ScrollView -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ScrollView>

</uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout>
```

This works great for stuff like `ListView`, `ScrollView`, `GridView`, etc. However, apparently this will not work for Fragments (Tabs & ViewPagers). Now, in the sample code he has wrapped the refreshable fragment with a `ScrollView` **INSTEAD** of a `PullToRefreshLayout`.

I cannot do this because my Fragment 1 (under tab 1) has a `GridView`. Now I cannot add a `GridView` to a `ScrollView` because that just wouldn't make sense.

For example, if I put my `GridView` inside the `ScrollView` as shown below, it just doesn't make sense:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ptr_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF000" >

        <!-- MY GRID VIEW -->

        <GridView
        ...
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The above code works. Sort of. *(I need to disable scrolling of my GridView and use an [ExpandableGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859250/how-to-put-gridview-inside-scrollview) to get it working properly... which seems like overkill & I'm not even sure if that would work)*.

If I replace the `ScrollView` wrapper with anything else like `PullToRefreshLayout` or any other layout, the refreshing doesn't work.

What to do? How to get my layout to work with this library without wrapping a `ScrollView` around it?

I hope I was clear enough. Please let me know if you need any more info. I tried to explain it the best I could.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue trying to get it to work with a ListView that I had in one of my tabs.

I solved my issue by using the PullToRefreshAttacher instead of using the layout.

In your Activity that is controlling the ViewPager for the fragments, initialize a PullToRefreshAttacher in onCreate or an init method.

```
mPullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this);
```

Next make a public method that allows access to the attacher that you just initialized.

```
public PullToRefreshAttacher getPullToRefreshAttacher() {
    return mPullToRefreshAttacher;
}
```

Then in the fragment you want the refresh functionality.

```
mPullToRefreshAttacher = ((MainTabActivity) getActivity())
            .getPullToRefreshAttacher();

mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(activeListView, this);
```

Except in your case activeListView would be the reference to your GridView instead of a ListView.

Then make sure your fragment implements OnRefreshListener so you can handle the Refresh.

I have not actually tested this with a GridView so let me know if it works.

Good Luck!

Comment: Wow! That solved it! I never tried doing this: `mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(myGridView, this);`

Instead of the GridView, I kept using PullToRefreshLayout. Your solution solved it. Thanks a lot, DejanRistic :)