# Android Scrollview + GridView not scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, scrollview

I have this structure:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/categories_listView"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="gone">

            </ListView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/cataloguesViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/productsGridView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                    android:numColumns="5"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:verticalSpacing="1dp">
                </GridView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/categories_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/categories_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/send_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity, I disable the `GridView` scroll

```
productsGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.productsGridView);
productsGridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I want all the views inside the `scrollView` scrolling, I mean, when I scroll up, all the elements inside the `GridView` should be shown and the `PagerView` should be gone.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: It's really a **worse** idea, to put **scrollable Views** inside a **scrollable View**...

Comment: Thanks @DerGolem, I know it, but for now I have to do it like this

Comment: I think the problem it's the nested scrollable views, i not reccomend you do this

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12859616/2640203

Comment: I know it's not recommended but...how can I implement this without putting scrollable Views inside a scrollView ??