# Scrolling is not worked in GridView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am doing an android application. In my application I wanted to **scroll GridView and some other items** in my layout at the **same time**. But when I add ScrollView to the parent layout, the GridView scrolling is not worked, it shows only first row of items. I tried **ScrollView , NestedScrollView** etc but did't get positive result.I don't know how to fix it, if anyone know it please help me.

**xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="activities.Home">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rlayout_menus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutmenu1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">



            <!--Offers-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_offers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/offer" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Offers"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--Menu-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_offers"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Menu"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--Exchange-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_exchange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_menu"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_exchange"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/exchange" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Exchange"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--Health-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_health"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_exchange"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/health" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Health"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <!--Less-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_less"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_health"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_less_more"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/less" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_less_more"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Less"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutmenu2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layoutmenu1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >


            <!--Bank-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_bank"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_offers"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/bank" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Bank"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <!--SOS-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_sos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_menu"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_bank"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/sos" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="SOS"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/Rlayout_menus"
            android:background="#F0F0F0" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_subCat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Search by Catagory"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_electronics"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rect_m"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/electronics"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Electronics"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_food"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rect_g"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/food"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="Food"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"

                        />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_cosmetics"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rect_b"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cosmetics"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Cosmetics"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"

                        />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_nonfood"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/elctronics_btn"
                        android:backgroundTint="#e2ef0e15"
                        android:text="Non Food"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"

                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_subCat"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#F0F0F0" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_company"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
            android:background="#E7E7E7">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_company"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Search by Company"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/company1"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:background="#FFF"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/company2"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/company1"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/company3"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/company2"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/company4"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/company3"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/company5"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/company4"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/company6"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/company5"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/company7"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/company6"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/home_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <ViewStub
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If you need a nested scroll, use NestedScrollView and RecyclerView, do not put Gridview into scrollview

Comment: I was also used NestedScrollView .but it's not working

Comment: do not use NestedScrollView and GridView, use it with Recyclerview. These are developed for working together.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enable your GridView Property

android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" It will work.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at this answer [How to put GridView inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859250/how-to-put-gridview-inside-scrollview/) ?

if you want to scroll Gridview anyway, use it in your parent layout(Linearlayout with weightSum) outside the scrollview's child layout