# Trying to get textView to stick to gridView scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-scroll

I have a fragment with a `textView` giving instructions, and below a `gridView`. I wanted for the `textView` to scroll upwards with the `gridView`. In other words: for `textView` to disappear off screen when `gridView` is scrolling.

My idea of how to accomplish this is to give the `gridView` a fixed height that would make the entire layout scrollable - including the `textView`. However, up until I cannot achieve this. Is there a way to do this?

**Layout no scroll:**

[image: Layout no scroll]

**When scrolled:**

[image: When scrolled:]

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

My layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/LightGrey"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:text="@string/chooseLine"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="130dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'd try setting gridView layout_height="wrap_content" then your linearLayout should allow you to scroll, the issue with that is then your grid view is creating all your views at once and not recycling them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieving this is is not going to be trivial. What you need is ListView's capability to add a header view, but unfortunately, GridView doesn't offer that functionality.

What I have done in the past to solve this problem is to convert the GridView to a ListView, and then add the header to the ListView. I created a wrapper adapter that takes the original adapter and combines a horizontal row's worth of grid cells into a single list row.

The tricky parts include: dynamically adapting the number of columns in a row based on the width of the screen, accounting for all combinations of view types within a row and remaining empty columns in the last row, and handling click interactions properly.

Answer (score 1):

Put the whole LinearLayout in a ScrollView ([How to use ScrollView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android)) and for the GridView set android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: This is a bad idea, and many people have recommended against it on SO, Android blogs, and more. The GridView itself scrolls, and it does not have an intrinsic content height, so wrap_content won't help you.

Comment: I've stumbled on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523609/grid-of-images-inside-scrollview/4536955#4536955

Which states my issue (I guess I hadn't looked hard enough before posting). 

I will try this, but I'm skeptical.