# Using non scrollable list within ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I know that a ListView is not allowed within a ScrollView in Android. But what if I make the ListView non scrollable which is the kind of UI I require? If not then is there any other widget that I can use in place of the ListView for such a case.

Comment: Just use a LinearLayout instead (orientation vertical) and inflate your rows in there with a simple for-loop. You will then have to implement the click listeners yourself ofcourse...

Comment: you can use vertical  linear layout instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4536955/488553) you are looking for.
You need to override the listview class and make sure you have constructor with attrs.