# How to create a gridview with spacing at the top

Tags: android, gridview

I was looking to create a `GridView` that stretches across the entire screen. However, when the user first opens the screen, the top of the first item should be about halfway up the screen.

For example lets say we have a `GridView` of 12 items displayed 3 x 4. When the user first opens the screen, only the first six items would be seen with a large margin at the top of the screen. The user can then scroll the list to see the other items. The top items would eventually reach all the way to the top of the screen.

If I was using a `ListView`, this is simple. I merely create a 0dp headerView with a large top margin. But, `GridViews` do not allow for headers. What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: In other words, you search to make a `ScrollView` with `GridView`, isnt it? (I mean `addHeaderView()` as a `ListView`)

Comment: Yes, a `ScrollView` with a `GridView` inside would be another way of putting it. But, I've always thought it was frowned upon putting `GridViews` inside of `ScrollViews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you **DO NOT** make a `GridView` inside a `ScrollView`. It's not recommended! But sometimes you have no choice and you need to `addHeaderView()` on a `GridView` (But I repeat, it isnt recommended).

So, to make this happen, you have to make a custom `GridView`. This answer will be usefull in your case: [Grid of images inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523609/grid-of-images-inside-scrollview)

I had a same situation and I used this one: `HFGridView` by [@SergeyBurish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404783/sergey-burish)! Very simple and really great. (See the last answer here: [A GridView with header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17849364/2668136)).

Hope this will be helpful.